# MPI_Neighbor_alltoall segfault

Tags: c++, mpi, openmpi

I was working on an MPI application that needs to use a (distributed) graph communicator for communicating between nodes. There are some cases where the easiest thing is for the nodes to communicate to themselves. While testing the code I ran into a problem with a segfault I couldn't explain. Here's a minimal example that reproduces the problem (in OpenMPI 1.8.1):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <mpi.h>

int main(void) {
    MPI_Init(NULL, NULL);

    MPI_Comm mpi_neighbor_comm;
    int v[2] = {0, 0}, w[2] = {0, 0};
    MPI_Dist_graph_create_adjacent(MPI_COMM_WORLD,
        2, v, (int *)MPI_UNWEIGHTED,
        2, w, (int *)MPI_UNWEIGHTED,
        MPI_INFO_NULL, 0, &mpi_neighbor_comm);

    int major, minor;
    MPI_Get_version(&major, &minor);
    std::cerr << "Version " << major << '.' << minor << std::endl;

    int indegree, outdegree, weighted;
    MPI_Dist_graph_neighbors_count(mpi_neighbor_comm, &indegree, &outdegree, &weighted);
    std::cerr << "Degrees: " << indegree << ", " << outdegree << std::endl;

    std::vector<int> in(indegree, 0), out(outdegree, 1);

    MPI_Neighbor_alltoall(&out[0], 1, MPI_INT,
        &in[0], 1, MPI_INT, mpi_neighbor_comm);

    std::cerr << in[0] << std::endl;

    MPI_Comm_free(&mpi_neighbor_comm);
    MPI_Finalize();

    return 0;
}
```

This gives the following output when run with 1 process:

```
$ mpiexec -n 1 ./mpi_test
Version 3.0
Degrees: 2, 2
1
[LMC-038262:51444] *** Process received signal ***
[LMC-038262:51444] Signal: Segmentation fault: 11 (11)
[LMC-038262:51444] Signal code: Address not mapped (1)
[LMC-038262:51444] Failing at address: 0x0
[LMC-038262:51444] *** End of error message ***
```

Since the value "1" got transmitted to `in`, it seems that the communication works - but the program then segfaults. What's wrong? The segfault disappears if I comment out the call to `MPI_Neighbor_alltoall`.

Comment: Works for me with Open MPI 1.8.5.

Comment: There is a changeset in 1.8.2 that affects some of the all-to-all functions. It doesn't specifically mention `MPI_Neighbor_alltoall`, but it could be that your case is a bug that has been resolved in 1.8.2 or later version.

Comment: Gah. I could update it on my own computer but given that this is something that's going to be run on clusters where I can't really choose the version, I rewrote it using Isend and Irecv. Seems to work ok now.